# Ubuntu 16.04 some applications take too long to start up

Tags: pdf, startup-applications, okular

When I start up Ubuntu 16.04 some applications take too long to run the first time I open them, including Chrome and any PDF viewer. Others, like nautilus, start up immediately.

The first time I try to use a PDF viewer like okular, it takes too long to open. After it opens a PDF file for the first time, other files open quickly. Even if I close all and open some after a long time, it happens quickly.

How can I speed up these programs opening on the first run?

Comment: Using an SSD would for sure speed things up - as reading data from disk is faster.

Answer (score 10):

I got the same problem out of the blue on my new notebook. After that I did a new ubuntu installation on a desktop machine, and the problem didn't happened there.

After some research, I found the solution [here on the Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180066)

Close all your apps (like Chrome) and try running the following command on a terminal:

```
gnome-keyring-daemon &
```

After that, open Chrome again. It might ask for your account password again once. For me this solves the delay problem. Chrome and gnome-terminal are opening very fast now (< 1 sec delay instead 30 sec delay).

For you knowledge, Chrome was throwing the following error before this fix:

> Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: Did not receive a reply.
>   Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

I logged Chrome startup with `strace`, and this message alone took 25 seconds to appear. I guess this is a system message, not only for Chrome, because I was having the same issue with gnome-terminal starting up as well, and this fix solve that issue too.

Comment: I have been fighting with this thing for a while and good job!  That is what it took.  Many thanks!  +1

Comment: The problem is with gnome-keyring-daemon for sure, but this answer didn't help me because there were `gnome-keyring-daemon` already running. This answer helped https://askubuntu.com/a/911755/61218

Comment: This command only works once. This happens every time with startup. Before shooting me elsewhere, could you update your post to explain what you've learned and what gnome-keyring-daemon & is and does? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could install `preload` and `ureadahead` and see if that helps.
Both can work together as far as i know - so they shouldnt conflict with each other.

## preload

### About

> preload is an adaptive readahead daemon that prefetches files mapped
>   by applications from the disk to reduce application startup time.

See its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/preload.8.html) for more.

### Installation

You could install `preload` via

```
sudo apt install preload
```

## ureadahead

### About

> ureadahead  (über-readahead)  is  used  during  boot  to  read files
>   in advance of when they are needed such that they are already in the  page
>   cache, improving boot performance.

### Installation

Install it via

```
sudo apt install ureadahead
```

While `ureadahead` is most likely installed already anyways.

Comment: How is it going to solve the problem actually? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

I seems that the bug is caused by the `dbus-user-session package` (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1689825), which prevent `gnome-keyring-daemon` from starting.

Uninstalling `dbus-user-session` can fix the problem.

```
sudo apt-get purge dbus-user-session
```

Comment: Wow! That wanted to remove a large pile of wanted applications.