# Gnome keyring daemon not starting up properly

Tags: unity, gnome, password, gnome-keyring

Since a few days ago my Gnome-keyring daemon hasn't been starting up properly.

After logging in:

```
ps aux | grep keyring
user       3496  0.0  0.0 214408 15800 ?        SLl  13:30   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
```

Apps complain about not being able to access the keyring (and fail to do so), some shortcuts are very slow <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for terminal or Print screen can both take up to a minute between key press and action)

Seahorse does not show the login keyring

```
$ /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
$ ps aux | grep keyr
user       3496  0.0  0.0 214408 15800 ?        SLl  13:30   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
user       8524  0.1  0.0 211004 12468 pts/5    SLl  13:38   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon
```

Then, as soon as an app wants to access I get the keyring password prompt. Once unlocked, the keyring works properly.

I had a look to startup apps for my session and I only have one command that is relevant:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh
```

I added `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon` to startup apps, but it will prompt for the keyring password after each login, which wasn't happening before.

Any idea on what happened and how to fix this please?

Comment: I actually wonder if an update might have caused this.  I am experiencing the exact same issue, and I have just about exhausted every single resource I have just shy of doing a complete reinstall.  I hope that someone might have figured this one out.   I am able to get the daemon to start up OK, but I cannot get the keyring to unlock at log in time.

Comment: see bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825

Comment: Strangely this is affecting me since today on 16.04.

Comment: I have the same problem on a `gnome-shell` (from Ubuntu Gnome 16.04) install. Started recently. So it seems not unity-related...

Comment: [@ByteCommander 's method](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825/comments/74) solved the problem for me. Thanks...

Comment: You should most likely uninstall the `dbus-user-session` package to permanently fix the issue, as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/936051/367990) below or in the [Launchpad bug report comments](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825/comments/74).

Comment: I have the same inclination as @Terrance that an update caused the Gnome keyring daemon not to start properly. I also get a crash report upon each start up: [gnome-keyring-daemon crashed with SIGABRT in g_assertion_message()](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1299512).   
dbus-user-session package is not installed on my machine and therefore not the culprit.

Answer (score 17):

I'm facing the same issue,

as an temporary solution try to run the following after login

```
gnome-keyring-daemon --replace --foreground --components=secrets,ssh,pcks11
```

When I'm doing this it prompts me to enter my secret to unlock my keyrings.

Comment: It still asks for the password to unlock the keyring

Comment: This worked great! But I just needed to remove the `--start` option because it's not compatible with `--replace`

Comment: chrome was taking to long to load, in terminal i type gnome-keyring-daemon, then close and open chrome , now i am able to type my password, thankyou

Comment: *pkcs11, not pcks11

Comment: This fixed it permanently for me.

Answer (score 12):

I could work around this problem by uninstalling `dbus-user-session` (and its dependendants `xdg-desktop-portal` and `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`). Those packages came in through installing flatpak.

Thanks to Olaf who brought me on the right track (https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/gnome-keyring-daemon-doppelt/)

Comment: this seem to work for several people, including me.  See this bug report starting at #67 for more info. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825

Comment: This should be the top answer as it permanently fixes the issue without any other side effects - except maybe that the application that wanted `dbus-user-session` installed might be slightly upset, but better just that one than the whole system.

Comment: It didn't solved it for me

Answer (score 5):

I've been able to fix the slow shortcut and hanging chromium, by commenting out one line in /etc/pam.d/lightdm

```
# session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

The issue seems to affect more users btw:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825

Comment: It still asks for the password to unlock the keyring

Comment: Hmm... I have the same problem, with `gnome-shell` and `gdm`, so this is probably not directly related. Thanks anyway, will explore `pam`... somewhere the `gnome-keyring-daemon` will have to be started

Comment: I run gnome-sheel too, so looking at the config I found a similar line in `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password`. I commented it out but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. Basically, whenever I started up, I could see the gnome-keyring-daemon as a process (ps -ef | grep keyring).  If I manually issued the gnome-keyring-daemon using --start option, it would not start up the one fault instance already running.  By a process of manual deduction, I found that if I killed that process and started a new keyring, then everything worked perfect.  so here is what I did to make the solution "sticky"....

go to menu - system configuration - startup apps

delete the gnome-keyring-daemon entry that is already there (if you have one)

create a new gnome-keyring daemon with the following properties:

```
Name = Gnome Keyring Daemon
Command = /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --replace --daemonize --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh
Comment = Gnome Keyring Manager Daemon
```

Save the startup item, but make sure it has a small delay - I added 10 seconds, and set the option "On"

Now Reboot, and it worked flawlessly for me.  It seemed to be the `--replace` and `--daemonize` settings that made the difference on my VirtualBox Mint 18.3 cinnamon and a Lenovo G710 Laptop, having tried various combinations of other suggestions on here.

Comment: Great answer. Solved the problem for me that Chrome couldnt start without keyring daemon

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if you are using `apparmor` and somehow (updates, something else) `apparmor` stops getting run on boot. You will get messages about `gnome-keyring-agent` not being able to allocate secure memory. Starting `apparmor`, logging out and logging in again fixes it temporarily, re-enabling `apparmor` on boot with `systemctl enable apparmor` and rebooting fixes this permanently (if that was your problem!).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here because of the following errors in my logs.

```
Mar 11 11:14:32 debian systemd[1899]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-2092.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Mar 11 11:14:32 debian systemd[1899]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-2098.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Mar 11 11:14:32 debian systemd[1899]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-2094.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
```

I could fix them by a slight modification of decocijo's answer.

In `/etc/xdg/autostart/` I could find the following three files

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8608 Mar 11 11:49 gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8136 Mar 11 11:49 gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6671 Mar 11 11:50 gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
```

on each of them comment and add one line, as for example in `gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop`

```
#Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --replace --daemonize --components=pkcs11
```

do the same with the other two files.

I am mainly writing this answer so that other people with these errors can find the answer but ultimately, this should not happen. I have a clean installation of Gnome 43 on Debian Bookworm.