# Chrome and Chromium are taking a long time to load

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, chromium

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.2 and today Google Chrome and Chromium started taking a long time to load. Once opened, they freeze frequently.

I loaded Chrome from the command line and got this message:

```
$ google-chrome
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
[8032:8100:0504/165233.258127:ERROR:connection.cc(1954)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: DELETE FROM cookies WHERE persistent != 1
[8032:8070:0504/165235.449471:ERROR:leveldb_database.cc(311)] Failed to open LevelDB database from /home/fd/.config/google-chrome/Default/IndexedDB/https_www.google.pt_0.indexeddb.leveldb,IO error: /home/fd/.config/google-chrome/Default/IndexedDB/https_www.google.pt_0.indexeddb.leveldb/LOCK: No further details. (ChromeMethodBFE: 15::LockFile::1)
[8032:8070:0504/165235.450323:ERROR:indexed_db_backing_store.cc(1403)] Unable to open backing store, not trying to recover - IO error: /home/fd/.config/google-chrome/Default/IndexedDB/https_www.google.pt_0.indexeddb.leveldb/LOCK: No further details. (ChromeMethodBFE: 15::LockFile::1)
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
[8032:8074:0504/165337.922687:ERROR:connection.cc(1954)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: COMMIT
```

Loading chromium from the command line returns this:

```
$ chromium-browser
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Killed
```

I already completely removed chrome/chromium, deleted their respective folders in .config and .cache

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have posted the following bug for this issue. Please add any relevant information and/or mark it as affecting you as well: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gnome keyring daemon not starting up properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898694/gnome-keyring-daemon-not-starting-up-properly)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved this by creating this file `~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-daemon.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Gnome Keyring Daemon
Name=Gnome Keyring Daemon
Comment[en_US]=Load gnome keyring daemon
Comment=Load gnome keyring daemon
```

Then I rebooted and Chrome/Chromium went back to normal ([source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180075)).

After rebooting I kept getting this message "keyring was not unlocked upon signin" and had to type my password. I got rid of it by following [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Comment: Did this give you some "keyring was not unlocked upon signin" message and prompt for the user-password?

Comment: Yes. I got rid of it by following these instructions:https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot

Comment: Clearing the keyring password cannot be an acceptable solution nor workaround

Comment: Actually [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/911755/61218) helped fix the issue cleanly

Comment: Starting gnome-keyring-daemon solving my worse symptom on a TigerVNC :1 of Debian Jessie: Chrome wouldn't start at all, even after allegedly timing out libsecret and "GNOME keyring" and reverting to "basic (unencrypted) store for password storage", per --enable-logging=stderr.

Comment: Are all these lines required? What do they do? Why do they solve the problem?