# Google Chrome can not start under VNC (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: google-chrome, vnc

Nothing happen when I click icon of Chrome under VNC, tried both GNOME and XFCE. No error log in VNC. I am using TigerVNC, Here is my `~/.vnc/xstartup`

```
#!/bin/sh
MODE="GNOME"
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
if [ -e "$HOME/.Xresources" ]
then
    xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
fi

if [ "GNOME" = "$MODE" ]
then
    if which gnome-session > /dev/null
    then
        gnome-session --session=ubuntu &
    else
        MODE=""
    fi
fi
```

If I enter `google-chrome` under terminal, I will get error:

```
[7027:7027:0622/011058.037849: ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(378)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

I can open other programs like Firefox under VNC without issue.

**Update 2018-06-24:**

If I delete ~/.config/google-chrome, I can open Chrome under VNC, but it took about 60 seconds to show up...

Once I logged in my Google account and close Chrome, I can not re-open it again...

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be two issues here.

1. GPU acceleration. You can resolve this by running

   ```
   google-chrome --disable-gpu
   ```
2. `gnome-keyring-daemon`. This is a [fairly common problem with a number of workarounds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911877/chrome-and-chromium-are-taking-a-long-time-to-load/911896). The most acceptable to me is to execute this before launching chrome:

   ```
   gnome-keyring-daemon --replace --foreground --components=secrets,ssh,pcks11
   ```

However, you may find one of the other options more acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. kill all chrome processes
2. kill the gnome-keyring-daemon
3. start chrome in VNC.

That worked for me in Fedora 28 with Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I had the EXACT same issue and error message.  I started using VNC :11 and on the main displkay doing vnc to 127.0.0.1:11 so that I can jump to another desktop on get to my desktop via chromebook and back without loosing my work.

Yes I could just vino but VNC is easier and I don't have it autostart so it's easier to secure (manually turn it on only when needed then off when I don't, etc) and easier to start on a mate desktop as I am NOT a gnome 3 fan at all!  If I want to see fancy graphics/animations I'll play *craft from blizzard or go watch cartoons.    :-D

Answer (score -1):

it is fixed by 
sudo apt install gnome-keyring

after starting chrome again .. wait somewhat longer than usual.

Et wholla!

Comment: I already have gnome-keyring installed... not working

Comment: In many cases definitely not fixed by installing gnome-keyring