# Google Chrome takes a long time to load

Tags: google-chrome

The first time I open Google Chrome after login, it takes ages to load. When it finally loads I can close it out and it opens normally. What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: file sync could be using up all of your cpu

Comment: @ravery Could you explain some more

Comment: google cloud services are usually set to auto synchronize. thus when you login it compare local files to cloud files using up processor time.

Comment: @ravery How do I fix this

Comment: turn off sync in preferences

Comment: @ravery If you add this as an answer I will set it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might run into the problem where `gnome-keyring-daemon` didn't start.

A workaround for me was to uninstall `dbus-user-session`.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/936051/358045.

Comment: This was exactly the cause in my case. However I simply rebooted it (twice actually) and it fixed the issue.

Comment: `dbus-user-session` is a required package and will cause many unwanted side effects if removed. Kind of like swatting a fly with a Buick.

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud auto-sync uses a lot of processor time.

Go to preferences and turn it off.

Comment: This didn't work. I even tried logging out. It didn't make a difference.

Comment: Not even resetting my settings helped

Comment: something else is an issue then.