# Chrome will not launch

Tags: google-chrome

Google chrome will not open at all. When I click on the icon for it in the launcher it flashes like it will open, the shortly after it closes. I have purged chrome from the system and re-installed it which worked, until I rebooted, then the same problem again.

Trying to launch it from the terminal it just appears to sit there until I manually quit it.

Comment: Using chromium now seems to be a viable workaround

Comment: Did you try to launch it from the terminal using `google-chrome`? What output did you get? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/956309/edit) and add the output in a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/898694/gnome-keyring-daemon-not-starting-up-properly. It helped when I had a similar problem

Answer (score -1):

This is a known bug in the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNOME) Software application, but you can install Google Chrome in an alternative way ... open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list  

wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -  

sudo apt-get update  

sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```