# Chromium failing to launch

Tags: 16.04, chromium

After running Software Updater to install 4.4.0.104 (Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit), when I try to launch Chromium it opens a new window but I just get a grey box.  It never finishes loading, and I have to kill it. Are some dependencies missing or corrupted?

Firefox seems to be working OK.

edit: I uninstalled Chromium and reinstalled it. The first time I opened it, it launched OK, but when I closed it and reopened it, the grey box came back. I wonder if the 'close' is maybe leaving something behind and not tidying up properly?

edit: typing 'chromium-browser' in a terminal returns
PPAPI flash has config file in /etc, but library does not exist and won't be used. Package is uninstalled, not purged.
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.

Comment: Could you have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/898694/367990 and check if it is related? What does `pgrep -af keyring` say?

Comment: 1616 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login

Comment: I left Terminal open. After I killed the unresponsive window (via the UI) I got: [1:1:0100/000000.387801:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(43)] Invalid node channel message
Not being an expert on Ubuntu, I don't know if this is the expected result of the Kill command, or if it is related to the problem.

Comment: Sorry, dunno what that last message could mean. The keyring daemon seems fine though, that's not the issue.