# Ubuntu 16.04 - Some applications are slow to start

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

Applications such as Chrome (no problem with other browsers), terminal, print screen, they all take ages (~1 minute) to start. All applications that I invoke with key-binding are slow. This has been going on for a couple of days.

Lenovo Yoga 500

Processor: AMD A8-7410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics × 4

Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD MULLINS (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-77-generic, LLVM 3.8.0)

OS Type: 64-bit

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
```

EDIT 1: output for `google-chrome`

```
[3871:3871:0509/102048.258355:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(343)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process. 
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

output for `gnome-screenshot` is immediate; it takes more than 1m when I press <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>.

Comment: Can you open the application from terminal and see what it says while opening and add them into the question?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and running the following command solved it:

```
gnome-keyring-daemon &
```

I found the solution in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/838985/690438

Edit:
The origin of the problem seems to be the dbus-user-session package. After uninstalling, everything works fine. The bug was solved here https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1689825

Comment: had same issue, this works on my side. Cheers.

Comment: Removing that package and rebooting fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what is this daemon, what it does etc?