# Ubuntu Keyboard shortcut to launch terminal is very slow

Tags: shortcut-keys, launcher, gnome-terminal

I frequently launch a terminal via keyboard command.  Normally it is very fast.  All my other launcher shortcuts still work quickly.  The terminal launcher is taking over 20 seconds before I see the terminal.  This just started a few days ago.
I've tried the following with no change:

- Changing the default terminal from `gnome-terminal.wrapper` to `terminator`.
- Creating a new custom shortcut.
- Changing the key sequence of the launcher.

All these resulted in the same 20+ second launch time.

Any ideas how to debug this issue further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the [same problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/913342/481215) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/912250/481215) helped a lot.

Apparently it's a bug within `gnome-keyring`, more info [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729101).